# 'Couldn't find that process type' heroku node deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I'm getting 'Couldn't find that process type' when I try to do `$ heroku ps:scale web=1`. I looked at some other solutions that suggested to make sure my Procfile is spelled correctly and pushed correctly, which is.

This is the exact error I get:

```
    heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/XXXXXX/.cache/heroku/error.log'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1316:33)
    at Object.fs.appendFileSync (fs.js:1362:6)
    at log (/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/6.6.7/libexec/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/lib/errors.js:87:6)
    at handleErr (/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/6.6.7/libexec/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/lib/errors.js:102:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Comment: I am getting a similar error, with a python deployment

Comment: I had to add a buildpack. Then I was able to push and the initial web process type was added automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, in my project, I wasn't pushing to the master branch, and I was performing the wrong git code. So the correct way to push to Heroku if you are working on a different branch is the following:

```
git push heroku <branch_name>:master
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the following answer is for Rails, it can certainly apply to any framework.

The app deployment logs are supposed to list these default types:

```
Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker
```

(this log is displayed when you run `git push`, you can also find them in the Activity feed of your Heroku dashboard)

If this line (or something similar) is not present, this might be due to the buildpacks of your app. You can list them with:

```
$ heroku buildpacks --app myapp
=== myapp Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/ruby
2. https://github.com/some/buildpack.git
```

In this example, `heroku/ruby` comes first, which might sounds legit. But it seems that the last buildpack cancels the types created by `heroku/ruby`. To fix this, make sure this buildpack comes last. You can achieve this with `buildpacks:remove` and `buildpacks:add --index`:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:remove https://github.com/some/buildpack.git --app myapp
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/some/buildpack.git --app myapp
$ heroku buildpacks --app myapp
=== myapp Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/some/buildpack.git
2. heroku/ruby
```

Deploy the app again with `git push`, and it is now possible to start `web` and `worker` processes.

Comment: I totally realize that this is not exactly the answer to the question, but this error message has little documentation on the web and this is definitely the kind of material I would have liked to find here.

Answer (score 0):

As Philippe mentioned heroku has many resource types, e.g. console, rake, web, worker.

My Procfile was

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

so

`heroku ps:scale web=0` worked for me